# Не устанавливаются библиотеки в venv через pip через файл requirements.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

При попытке установки через pip install -r requirements.txt
Терминал выдает ошибку:

raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/smart-json-log-formatter/

Comment: Нет такого пакета на PyPI, с именем `smart-json-log-formatter`. Или был, но удалили. Есть `json-log-formatter`, `simple-json-log-formatter` и т.д. Узнай у автора `requirements.txt`, что это за пакет и где его брать.

Comment: Ошибка перестала выпадать после обновления pip
Потому что теперь он смог подключиться к локальному репозиторию.